# How do the C streams system works?

Tags: c, libc

How do the C stream system works?

For example, the code:

```
FILE *f;
// opens f...
fputc(f, "x");
```

will do different things, depending on how 'f' was open. If 'f' was open as a file, a character will be written in that file. If 'f' was open as a memory stream, a char will be written in the memory, and possibly more memory will be alloced.

So my question is: how does the fputc function knows what 'f' means and what to do with it?

Aditional question: does it depend entirely on the operating system or is it possible to implement something a abstract interface like this in pure C?

Comment: On all platforms I've seen the `f*` functions _are_ implemented in pure C, using lower level system calls.

Comment: in kernel this is typically implemented with storing the function pointers for the various calls.

Comment: Where did you find memory streams using the `FILE *` interface?

Comment: `open_memstream` in glibc, [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_11.html#SEC166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open function stores that information inside the `FILE` structure that `f` points to. It's pure C, though the low-level code to do the writing to the file will be platform-dependent.

Comment: What information? How do the `fgetc` function "knows" what to do, if it must store the data on a file or in the memory? Is this information inside `fgetc` body or somewhere else?

Comment: The `fgetc` function knows what to do because it looks inside the `FILE` structure that `f` points to at the information that the various `open` functions put there. It's likely not in `fgetc` itself but in lower-level functions `fgets` calls.